# R sapply and as.POSIXct running out of memory

Tags: r, datetime, memory, posixct

I have a dataframe called `t` of 57247 rows of 27 variables. The data frame was imported from a 16 MB .tsv file, so it is not that huge. One of these columns is `approved_date` which contains factors that are MySQL timestamp strings. An example is `"2007-10-08 06:38:18"`.

I have a function that converts this string into a POSIXct, an integer. I want to do this for the whole column.

```
convert_datetime <- function(dt) as.POSIXct(dt, tz="Asia/Hong_Kong")
```

When I try with the first 10 rows, everything works fine: the timestamps are converted to ints.

```
x <- head(t, 10)
x$approved_date <- sapply(x$approved_date, convert_datetime)
```

However, when I try with the whole table,

```
t$approved_date <- sapply(t$approved_date, convert_datetime)
```

RStudio uses up to 6 GB of RAM and runs out of memory. So clearly I am doing something wrong here. How can I get the functionality I want? Using R v3.0.2.

Comment: You likely have something else going on here. I'm doing the `sapply` code (deemed inefficient by Hong Ooi, and I agree) with a 100k row data.frame, and though it's certainly *slow*, it works with ~200MB of RAM committed (according to taskmgr). (R-3.3.3, win10/64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, R 3.0 is super-old. You really should upgrade if possible.

Second, as.POSIXct is vectorised.

```
x$approved_date <- as.POSIXct(x$approved_date, tz=*)
```

Comment: That did it! Any idea why the sapply method uses so much memory?

Comment: I updated to the latest version of R (3.4.1) and `sapply` takes longer but no longer uses so much memory.